# Cross Domain Issue in Production

Tags: javascript

I have an application ,that is accessing url from different domain.
This is working fine in my QA environment but getting below security pop up
"This page is accessing information that is not under it's control.This poses a security risk.Do you want to continue"

But the same code is throwing "Access Denied" error in Production

Both are running in HTTPS protocol

I am not seeing "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" Response Headers in Both QA and Production.
Both have same respone headers

Below is my javascript code

```
try {
    oXMLHttp.open("POST", "https://www.developer.com?id=2"), false);
    oXMLHttp.send(sQueryString);
}
catch (err) {
    alert("error")
    return;
}
```

Please suggest why my application is failing in production environment,

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: www.developer.com should be returning a Access-Control-Allow-Origin which contains either * or the exact domain you are calling from. Make sure you own www.developer.com or that it returns * for that header

Comment: use relative paths in your post request

Comment: this might help [The "Same Origin" security policy](http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy)

Answer (score 0):

I think my QA is running in Intranet Zone and My Production is running in Internet Zone.
So failing in Production